# ValueError: Layer model_20 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using Colab for training for images, also i using Vgg16 dataset.
but while train my model, I encounter this error.

```
ValueError: Layer model_20 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

I saw the answers of people with the same error as me, but it doesn't apply.
this other people answer

```
model.fit(generator, epochs=0, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
```

but not fixed.

This my code.

```
# train the model
model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)
# train the model, run epochs manually and save after each epoch
epochs = 20
steps = len(train_descriptions)
for i in range(epochs):
   # create the data generator
   generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
   # fit for one epoch
   model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
   # save model
   model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

Comment: Can you add `data_generator` function?

Comment: I put it in from the beginning, but I can't.

Comment: What do you mean by *I can't*? I meant the function definition itself.

Comment: I add data_generator function but the same symptoms are present.

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue. Thanks!